# Deploy tensorflow retrained inception model with new categories into cloud

Tags: tensorflow

I was retrained tensorflow inception final layer with my desktop.i want to deploy the retrained_graph.pb file into google ml engine.how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you face any specific issues following some deployment guide, say https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models?